# How to validate emails listed for Companies/Clients that are stored in multiple fields?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, email-validation, email-verification

I am trying to get emails that are listed in more than one field for companies/clients that are registered in my database tables to be validated when signing up on my site with the registered company/client email(s). I currently have one table for companies (tbl_companies) and one table for clients (tbl_clients) where I store the emails for both that are listed in the email, email1, and email2 fields via my admin panel. Once the emails listed are stored in either table the company/client then registers the email(s) listed for them via a company_signup form, which sends them an email with a verification link to verify their access to their company/client admin panel to modify their profiles.

The issue I am having is currently after listing all of the emails for the companies/clients in both of the tables the company_signup form only sees the emails that are in the email field for tbl_companies (email) and tbl_clients (email). I would like it to see both the email, email1, and email2 field from tbl_companies and tbl_clients when the company_signup form checks for the email being validated for registration and verification.

So far I have tried SELECT *, UNION, JOIN, and WHERE for SQL functions to try merging the tbl_companies and tbl_clients together using their ability to call more than one field in the two table to have them checked.

I have the functions called in a class.php which is included in both the company_form.php, client_form.php of my admin panel and company_signup.php of my signup form.

This is the code from my class.php page

```html
  public function get_email_artist($email){
  
   $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_music_artists WHERE email ='{$email}' 
OR email1 ='{$email}' 
OR email2 ='{$email}'";
   
   $this->data = $this->fetch_row_assoc($this->sql);
   if(!empty($this->data))
    return $this->data; 
   else{
    return false; 
   }  
  }

  public function get_email_company($email){
  
   $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_music_companies WHERE email ='{$email}' 
OR email1 ='{$email}' 
OR email2 ='{$email}'";
   
   $this->data = $this->fetch_row_assoc($this->sql);
   if(!empty($this->data))
    return $this->data; 
   else{
    return false; 
   }  
  }

  public function get_company_email($email){
  
   $this->sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email ='{$email}'";
   
   $this->data = $this->fetch_row_assoc($this->sql);
   print_r($this->data);exit;
   if(!empty($this->data)){
    return $this->data; 
   }
   else{
    $sql = "(SELECT email, email1, email2 FROM tbl_music_artists WHERE email ='{$email}' 
OR email1 ='{$email}' 
OR email2 ='{$email}')
      UNION
      (SELECT email, email1, email2 FROM tbl_music_companies WHERE email ='{$email}' 
OR email1 ='{$email}' 
OR email2 ='{$email}')
      ";
    $data = $this->fetch_row_assoc($sql);
    if(!empty($data)){
     return false;
    }
    return true;
   }  
  }
```

```html
  public function register_company($inputs)
  {
   if(is_array($inputs)){
    // $pwdHasher = new PasswordHash(8, FALSE);
    // $hash is what you would store in your database
    // $hash = $pwdHasher->HashPassword( $_POST['com_password'] );
    $hash = base64_encode($_POST['com_password']);

    $uname = preg_replace('/@.*?$/', '', $_POST['com_email']);
    $uname .= rand();
    $input_array = array(
     'email'   => trim($_POST['com_email']),
     'u_type'   => 'company',
     'password'   => $hash,
     'username'   => $uname,
     'name '   => ucwords($_POST['com_name']),
     'phone'   => $_POST['com_phone'],
     'city '   => $_POST['com_city'],
     'country'   => $_POST['com_country'],
     'website'  => $_POST['com_url'],
     'gender'   => $_POST['com_gender'],
     'security_question'  => $_POST['com_quest'],
     'security_answer'  => $_POST['com_ans'],
     'status'   => 0,
    );
    
    $data = $this->get_email_artist(trim($_POST['com_email']));
    if($data) {
      $this->sendRegisterEmailCompany(array($data[email],$data[email1],$data[email2]), ucwords($_POST['com_name']));
      return $this->insert($input_array, 'login');
    }
    else {
     $data = $this->get_email_company(trim($_POST['com_email']));
     if($data) {
      $this->sendRegisterEmailCompany(array($data[email],$data[email1],$data[email2]), ucwords($_POST['com_name']));
      return $this->insert($input_array, 'login'); 
     }
     else{
      return 'invalid input';      
     }    
    }
   }
   else{
    return 'invalid input';
   }
  }

  public function sendRegisterEmailCompany($email, $name)
  {
   // ini_set("SMTP","smtp.vianet.com.np");
     // ini_set("smtp_port","25");
   $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/company_validate.php?identifier=' . base64_encode($email);
   
   $message = '<html><body>';
   $message .= '<h1>World Music Listing</h1>';
   $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
   $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td>Dear {$name},<br /> You have signed up successfully in the wml guide directory.<br />Before we can proceed please <strong>confirm</strong> your email address. <a href='$url'>Click here</a> OR copy below url and paste into your browser</td></tr>";
   $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td>$url</td></tr>";
   $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td>With Regards, <br />World Music Listing</td></tr>";
   $message .= "</table>";
   $message .= "</body></html>";

   $to = $email;

   $subject = 'Company Sign up successful notification- WML Guide';

   $headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
```

This is the code in my ajax.php

```html
  //////// Do not Edit below /////////
  try {
   $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_name.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password);
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
   print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
   die();
  }
  // Select all artists (clients) and order by name //
  $sql = "SELECT email, email1, email2 
FROM tbl_music_artists 
WHERE email ='{$com_email}' OR email1 = '{$com_email}' OR email2 = '{$com_email}'
UNION
SELECT email, email1, email2 
FROM tbl_music_companies 
WHERE email ='{$com_email}' OR email1 = '{$com_email}' OR email2 = '{$com_email}'";
    
  $data = $this->fetch_row_assoc($sql);
  
  if(!empty($data)){
     $valid = true;
   echo json_encode($valid);
  }
    else{
   echo json_encode($valid);
  }
   };
```

This is the code for my company_signup page

```html
 <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="page-heading">
     <h1>World Music Listing Company Registration</h1>
     <hr />
    </div>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) { ?>
     <div class="alert alert-error"><?php echo $_SESSION['error']; unset($_SESSION['error']); ?></div>
     <?php } ?>
     <form class="form-style-1" id="register" method="POST" action="signupcompanycontroller.php">
      <ul class="form-style-1">
       <li class="bottom"><label>Account Details</label></li>
          <li>
              <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
              <input type="email" name="com_email" class="field-long" placeholder="enter your email address" size="50" required />
          </li>
          <li>
           <label>Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" name="com_password" class="field-long" placeholder="enter password" size="50" required id="password" />
       </li>
       <li>
           <label>Confirm Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="password" name="com_conpassword" class="field-long" placeholder="enter confirm password" size="50" required />
       </li>
       <li class="bottom"><label>Personal Details</label></li>
       <li>
           <label>Full Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="com_name" class="field-long" placeholder="enter your full name" size="50" required />
       </li>
       <li>
           <label>Phone <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="com_phone" class="field-long" placeholder="enter your phone number" size="50" required />
       </li>
       <!-- <li>
           <label>Street Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="com_address" class="field-long" placeholder="enter your Street Address" size="50" />
       </li> -->
       <li>
           <label>City <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="com_city" class="field-long" placeholder="enter your city name" size="50" required />
       </li>
       <li>
           <label>Country <span class="required">*</span></label>           
           <select name="com_country" class="field-divided" required>
            <option value="">Select One</option>
            <?php
             $country_list = country();
             foreach ($country_list as $key => $value) {
              if(!empty($value))
               echo '<option>' . $value . '</option>';
             }
            ?>
           </select>
       </li>
       <li>
           <label>Website</label>
        <input type="url" name="com_url" class="field-long" placeholder="enter website url" size="50" />
       </li>
       <li>
           <label>Gender</label>
        <select name="com_gender" class="field-divided">
            <option value="">Select One</option>
            <option>Male</option>
            <option>Female</option>
           </select>
       </li>
       <li class="bottom"><label>Security</label></li>
       <li>
           <label>Security Question <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <select name="com_quest" class="field-long" required>
            <option value="">Select One</option>
            <option value="What is the name of your favorite pet?">What is the name of your favorite pet?</option>
                           <option value="What is your preferred musical genre?">What is your preferred musical genre?</option>
                           <option value="What is the street number of the house you grew up in">What is the street number of the house you grew up in?</option>
                           <option value="What time of the day were you born?">What time of the day were you born?</option>
                           <option value="What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?">What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?</option>
                           <option value="What is the name of the company of your first job?">What is the name of the company of your first job?</option>
                           <option value="What is the middle name of your oldest sibling?">What is the middle name of your oldest sibling?</option>
                           <option value="What is the middle name of your oldest child?">What is the middle name of your oldest child?</option>
                           <option value="What was the last name of your third grade teacher?">What was the last name of your third grade teacher?</option>
                           <option value="What was your childhood nickname?">What was your childhood nickname?</option>
                           <option value="What is your spouse’s mother’s maiden name?">What is your spouse’s mother’s maiden name?</option>
                           <option value="What is your mother’s maiden name?">What is your mother’s maiden name?</option>
                           <option value="What was your high school mascot?">What was your high school mascot?</option>
                          </select>
       </li>
       <li>
           <label>Answer</label>
        <input type="text" name="com_ans" class="field-long" placeholder="enter your answer" size="50" required />
       </li>
       <li class="bottom"><label>Terms and Mailing</label></li>
       <li>
        <label class="term"><input type="checkbox" name="com_terms" value="1" required class="condition"> <span class="required">*</span> <span id="terms">I accept the Terms and Conditions</span></label>
        <!-- <label><input type="checkbox" name="com_offer" value="1"> I want to receive personalized offers by your site</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="com_offer_partner" value="1"> Allow partners to send me personalized offers and related services</label> -->

       </li>
       <li>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" id="form_submit" />
       </li>
         </ul>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="termscondition" style="display: none;" title="Terms and Conditions">
  A. By using or visiting the World Music Listing website or any World Music Listing products, software, data feeds, including but not limited to its music/entertainment directory/list of contacts, and services provided to you on, from, or through the World Music Listing website (collectively the "Service") you signify your agreement to (1) these terms and conditions (the "Terms of Service"), (2) World Music Listing's Privacy Policy, found at http://www.wmlmusicguide.com/terms.php and incorporated herein by reference, and (3) World Music Listing's Community Guidelines, found at http://www.wmlmusicguide.com/terms.php and also incorporated herein by reference. If you do not agree to any of these terms, the World Music Listing Privacy Policy, or the Community Guidelines, please do not use the Service.
  
  <a href="terms.php" target="_blank">Please read more</a>
 </div>
<!--  end content-outer......END --> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="public/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
 <script>
  $().ready(function(){
   $('#register').validate({
          rules: {
              com_email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      remote: 'ajax_company.php'
      },
     com_password: {
      minlength: 6, 
      required: true 
      },
              com_conpassword: {
      equalTo : '#password;'
      },
              com_name: {
      minlength: 3, 
      required: true 
      },
              com_phone: {
      required: true 
      },
              com_city: {
      required: true 
      },
              com_country: {
      required: true 
      },
              com_quest: {
      required: true 
      },
              com_ans: {
      required: true 
      },
              com_terms: {
      required: true 
     }
          },
          messages: {   
     com_email: {
      remote: 'Entered email address not found.'
     }
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
              if (element.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
                  error.insertAfter($('.term'));
              } else {
                  error.insertAfter(element);
              }
          }  
   });

   $('.condition').click(function () {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              $('#termscondition').dialog({
               modal: true,
               width: 600,
         buttons: {
             Ok: function() {
                $( this ).dialog('close');
          }              
         }
              });
          } else {
              $('#termscondition').dialog('close');
          }
      });
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are only selecting against the first email field. If you want to check against all email fields you need to update your WHERE condition like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT email, email1, email2 
FROM tbl_music_artists 
WHERE email ='{$com_email}' OR email1 = '{$com_email}' OR email2 = '{$com_email}'
UNION
SELECT email, email1, email2 
FROM tbl_music_companies 
WHERE email ='{$com_email}' OR email1 = '{$com_email}' OR email2 = '{$com_email}'
```

EDIT:

This function:

```
$data = $this->get_email_artist(trim($_POST['com_email']));
```

Must return all the email addresses.

Then this function needs to email all the addresses:

```
$this->sendRegisterEmailCompany(trim($_POST['com_email']), ucwords($_POST['com_name']));
```

At the moment it just sends to the $_POST['com_email']. It depends on that function but you should be able to pass it an array of the email addresses ie:

```
$this->sendRegisterEmailCompany(array($data['email1'],$data['email2'],$data['email3']), ucwords($_POST['com_name']));
```

Comment: Depending on this function (sendRegisterEmailCompany), you would either need to pass an array of all the email addresses from the query result, or call it once for each email address.

$this->sendRegisterEmailCompany(array($data[email1],$data[email2]), ucwords($_POST['com_name']));

Comment: Thank you very much, would this be the same reason why only the first email from both the tbl_music_artists and tbl_music_companies receive the email notification with the verification link? I get the company_signup form to see the emails listed in all three fields within both tables, but only the email address listed in the first email field of tbl_music_artists receives the email. ['com_email'] is the name of the email field on the company_signup.php page.

Comment: I may be missing something, but the email with the verification link still doesn't get sent to the email addresses listed in the email1, and email2 fields.

Comment: I've update the answer to show you the relevant bits relating to your email send.

Comment: Then would "$input_array = array(
     'email'   => trim($_POST['com_email'])," this line need to be changed as well?

Comment: No input array doesn't need to change. You use the email from input array to look up the record in the db. Then use the returned record to get the other email addresses for your sendRegisterEmailCompany() function. It's pretty much all there in my edit.